# .htaccess redirect to a single subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

I have a website like `www.example.com`, I want to redirect each hit to this URL and Sub URL to a single URL on subdomain. Following are some examples

`www.example.com` should be redirected to `http://test.example.com`

`www.example.com/show/mypage1` should be redirected to `http://test.example.com`

`www.example.com/show/mypage2` should be redirected to `http://test.example.com`

`www.example.com/show/mypage3` should be redirected to `http://test.example.com`

I want to do it using `.htaccess`. and I want `302 temporary redirect`. I am using Apache WebServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Apache or IIS?

In Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.example.com/ [L,R=302]
```

*edited*

*edited: replaced `http://test.example.com/$1` to `http://test.example.com/`, it works now as required.*

Comment: I am using Apache, how will your code will redirect to `http://test.example.com` I can't see any reference to it?

Comment: @Ummar, It won't. That code will strip out a `www.` prefix, which is the answer to a completely different question.

Comment: The rewrite string uses regular expression string as you can see, so the request will be forwarded to the new domain

Comment: @TRiG, Then how to do it, please let me know?

Comment: You will need to add mod_rewrite to your Apache server config, most common one on a new system using terminal is: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: If that won't work you should find a `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so` file in your path and add it to your `modules {}` section in your apache2 httpd.conf file

Comment: The third line says it should redirect to `http://test.example.com` and the three lines can be added inside a .htaccess file or apache2 conf file

Comment: Thanks it works fine with little change, Please see my edit in your answer.

Comment: @Ummar. This version will redirect `http://www.example.com/page_url` to `http://test.example.com/page_url`. My version will drop `/page_url`, which is what you asked for.

Comment: No @blomman9, I need what you are saying, but your code was redirecting `http://www.example.com/page_url` to `http://test.example.com/page_url` which I don't want... I have tested it and changed it then.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.example.com/ [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```